# Can I refresh chromium web page from crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, xdotool

Is there any method for this? Actually, I tried some script, but I can not do it.

```
WID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class chromium|head -1)
xdotool windowactivate ${WID}
xdotool key ctrl+F5
```

Comment: Okey, I understand ,thank you for everything.

Comment: what happens if you just add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of script, save as file `myUpdater.sh`, make the file executable with `chmod +x myUpdater.sh` and then make a crontab entry like `* -0/23 * * *  /path/to/myUpdater.sh` ? You may need to add `PATH=/path/to/dir/containing/xdtool` at the top of your script. I may have missed something in the crontab syntax, so dbl-check that, and I hope you understand about having the correct `PATH` available inside the script. Good luck.

Comment: could the script be wrong ?

Comment: Does your code work from the cmd-line? I don't know anything about `xdtool`, just scripting in general. Try what I recommend, if it doesn't work, then update your Q with the complete code, any error messages. Do you know how to make a crontab entry that will run 1 time for specific min,hour,day,month (for testing)? Figure that out too.  use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: If you really wanted javascript code, Sorry. You should change the `bash` tag to javascript. Regular readers here filter questions based on tags, so you need to alert javascript readers that you need help. As your headline says `... crontab`, I'm assuming that a linux/cron/bash script solution should work for you. Good luck.

Comment: Does the underlying command work? `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class chromium|head -1`

Comment: Did you set the `DISPLAY` environment variable first? `export DISPLAY=":0"` I think `xdotool` needs that to be set.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using crontab to refresh a displayed webpage you have many other, more flexible options:

- use a chrome plugin (beware of spyware)
- create a new "monitor" html page to display the content

If you create a new html page to monitor some content you will have the most flexibility (you can set the refresh rate in the header and fetch the external source to display or refresh certain sections only, put in your own content, etc).  I found this to be the most flexible approach.

I found this forum which maybe useful if you must use cron:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/780337/how-to-open-an-url-in-firefox-via-cron-cron-jobs-scheduling